# Apache could not reliably determine server

Tags: server, apache2

Apache cannot fully determine domain name when I tried restarting after install.

I get this error;

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
Restarting web server config apache2
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain
name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName.
```

Why am I seeing **127.0.1.1**?
I have tried saving `ServerName localhost` into my `/etc/init.d/apache2` but it keeps redirecting me to Google search page every time I type `phpmyadmin`.

Will appreciate any expert help.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is a specific reason you need it to determine it there is no real reason to try and do so. I run 3 soon to be 5 sites on my server and at every restart it still says that. It seems to only be important in very specific cases.

Answer (score 0):

Line:

```
ServerName localhost
```

should be added to `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` or to some specific site in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`. The configuration can vary on different versions but `httpd.conf` should be there always.

Comment: It is not working still redirecting to google.

Comment: Did it still give a warning while restarting apache2? Did you explicitly add http to beginning? http://localhost ? (Chrome is at least trying to be "smart" sometimes). Does http://127.0.0.1 work?

Comment: Did not work? Still fighting with it.

Comment: If even 127.0.0.1 doesn't work, then there's something else wrong with configuration. How did you install the apache2?

Answer (score 0):

As default the configurations of apache is blank. Try to set with this.

Open terminal, and edit /etc/apache2/httpd.conf ,

set Servername localhost

Besure u have changed httpd.conf with right.

Restart with this command :

sudo service apache2 stop

sudo service apache2 start

See image below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, I've tried that approach with no success could it be because of this command I inputted? **sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/phpmyadmin**  Is this an accurate command? Thanks.

Comment: The command u input :sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/phpmyadmin not related with ur problem, because ur command just fix phpmyadmin so u can access from localhost right? I think u must remove apache and friends first and install again. Using this command: sudo apt-get remove apache2 php5 phpmyadmin and install again using this: sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 php5-mysql phpmyadmin

Comment: This is what happens when I tried to reinstall; **sudo apt-get remove apache2 php5 phpmyadmin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package apache2 is not installed, so not removed
Package php5 is not installed, so not removed
Package phpmyadmin is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  php5-gd libmcrypt4 php5-mcrypt apache2-mpm-worker dbconfig-common
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.** Not sure why it can't let me reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify ( Optional ) name of the site in apache configuration. 
Edit `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` file.

Add following parameter

```
Servername <your-website-name>
```

For example

```
 Servername ketan.in
```

Restart apache

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```